# Populating cells with text using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select a value from one sheet and put it in a cell on a different sheet.

My script determines the proper value but I cannot get the value into the sheet.

This function returns the !Value error on the 6th line of the following excerpt:

```
Function PrintTest(Cell)
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim bs As Worksheet
Set bs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("By System")
iRow = Cell.Row
bs.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = "Hello World"
End Function
```

I also tried using `.Text`.

Note: In the actual Script the text will be seeded from the other sheet and I have it stored in a variable. I am not looking for a way to get the same text into many different cells.

Update: `Cell` is passed from an Excel spreadsheet as an empty cell G4. `Row` is defined as 4. To call the functions I have been typing "=PrintTest(G4)" in my Excel worksheet named "By System" .

Update 2: Scott Holtzman answered the question in a comment. You cannot write to cells from a UDF called from within a cell. The fix was to call it from a button.

Comment: what is the value of `Row` when you get the error? I ask because `Cell` is undefined. Perhaps `Cell as Range` in the function argument. Also, why is this a function, it does not return any results?

Comment: I am passing in Cell G4 as Cell. Row then comes out as 4. G4 is an empty cell with general formatting. This is a function honestly because my intentions for it changed halfway through. I know its not great practice but Having a function that returns nothing should still work. right? Also, `Cell As Range` did not fix the problem. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: i just tested and it works perfect for me. Also Scott below made a good point about the variable name `Row`. Change it to `iRow` or something since `Row` is a keyword reserved in Excel.

Comment: I just saw your last edit. You cannot write to cells when calling a UDF from the worksheet via formula. You will need to have a button click or something run this.

Comment: Thank You! I made it run from a button click and that worked perfectly!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - could you have the UDF call a sub that writes to cells?

Comment: @BruceWayne - not sure, never tried. test it out ...

Answer (score 0):

Set a cell value with Cells(Row, Col).Value="Some text"
If your sheet is active you do not need to fully qualify the address. If you activate the sheet you can just use Cells all of the time. If you have to retrieve data from a different sheet then you will have to qualify the address with the sheet name, i.e. Sheets("My Sheet").Cells(Row, Col).Value.

Also your code has Row=Cell.Row, but you are not saying what cell is active. In that case you are getting some arbitrary value. So that is where your error is, probably. Cell.Row=????? Also Row is an excel word. Use something like intRow for your variable. For example intRow=25. Cells(intRow, 6).Value="My Cell". If the cursor is on a cell you can say intRow=ActiveCell.Row.

When you have a problem such as this set a break point in your code (in your example, the Set statement). Thenm run your code. When it stops at the set statement you can hit F8 to step through one line at a time and examine your variables. Then you will see if Row is really a number or just garbage.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Scott, I Updated the question to be more detailed. I need the full location because this is only part of the script, I will need to draw from 2 different sheets and don't want the window to constantly be switching as this script will run about 70 times. I am passing in Cell G4 When I call the function so `Row` has been getting defined as 4